# Upload File automatically on page load in React Component Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

Basically, I have an Excel file and want to show their data in react js tables on page load. To accomplish this, I want to upload file automatically on page load and show file data in the table but the file will not upload on page load.

> Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```js
<span onLoad={(e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    this.readExcel(file);
}}>File Uploaded</span>
```

Comment: This won't work. A span tag has neither an onload event or the ability to upload a file. Download the file from the server after the first render of the component.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do this.